# Setting variables to None in GDAL/Python

Tags: python, gdal

Is there a rule I can follow to know when I need to set something to `None` at the end?

I had a script where I was looping through a shapefile layer. I had only set the variable with the `ogr.Open(file)` to `None` at the end.

However, when I ran the same script again, I realized it was retaining that layer information and different times running the script would give me different results until I also set the layer to `None` at the end.

I'm not quite understanding what times I need to do this.

Comment: Exactly how are you running your script? You will need to set things to None if running from spyder or jupyter notebooks as they keep the python process/kernel alive which stops the data objects getting garbage collected which in turn stops GDAL writing the data to disk.

Comment: @user2856 In a Python script. I'm just running the file. Was running into errors until I set the layer (of the Shapefile I was iterating on) to None at the end of the script.

Comment: Show us some code that replicates the issue (will help get your question re-opened) as it is, you haven't provided enough info.